# Would casting a value to text and back to its original type always work in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say a value `v` of type `t` is used as follows in a SQL statement: `SELECT (v::text)::t;`, could this throw an error? Would the behaviour change for types introduced through extensions?

Comment: Interesting. For the basic types that come with pg by default, as well as composite types, I can't think of any case where this wouldn't work. As long as it's not an anonymous ROW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xtypes.html) observes:

> You should be careful to make the input and output functions inverses of each other. If you do not, you will have severe problems when you need to dump your data into a file and then read it back in. This is a particularly common problem when floating-point numbers are involved.

This shows the design principle that the built-in types adhere to when it comes to text input and output, and cast to and from `text` typically uses these functions.

So yes, it is like you want for built in types — mostly.

There are small exceptions, and the quotation hints at one of them: casting a `double precision` to and from `text` cannot be completely faithful, and you can lose (insignificant) digits (unless you set `extra_float_digits` to 3).

So that will work well for the built-in types. One simple reason why this is necessary is that otherwise `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` would not be able to create a dump that can be restored without data loss.

With user-defined types it depends on how well the implementors implemented the design principle. Usually they have to, since otherwise they would break `pg_dump`.